# Code execution of in app purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, in-app-purchase

How exactly does one download code or a binary and link to it at runtime, and setting the application to load this binary at runtime?

I would like to have in app purchases that get downloaded in binary form and are loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, on a non-jail broken device, you *can not* download code for your application to execute at runtime. The closest you can do is have the code in your application already but never execute it unless it's downloaded a token of some sort that permits (within your application logic) the code to run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can download arbitrary code from in-app purchases. I suppose your app will be rejected by Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Comment: It's not just a rejection issue. The iOS platform requires code to be signed using a key the device knows about -- primarily Apple's keys. They sign apps that are hosted on the store. This is why alternative app stores are only available for jailbroken devices (since part of the jailbreak is to remove the signing requirement).